# Java RESTful Webservice - FileNotFound

Tags: java, web-services, rest

i have a problem with writing a REST API. I wrote a little client to test the service, but i keep getting exceptions and errors.

Here's some of my code:

The deployment descriptor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"     
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">


<display-name>com.boss.rest.example</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ConfigServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ConfigServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The client code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
   try {
        String url_str = "http://localhost:8080/com.boss.rest.example/api/getRandomRamp";
        URL url = new URL(url_str);
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        System.out.println("Response code: " + c.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println(c.getInputStream().toString());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the servlet code:

```
@Path("/api")
public class ConfigServlet {

@Context
UriInfo uriInfo;

@GET
@Path("/getRandomRamp")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getRandomRamp() {
    String s = ">> This is just a random string, no real interaction with the backend available yet! <<";
    System.out.println("Service SysOut: " + s);
    return Response.status(200).entity(s).build();
}

}
```

With this code i get a FileNotFoundException for the given URL. Can anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have an issue with your api path. You have defined root path("/api/") at 2 places. Once in your deployment descriptor and the other in your Servlet. Change one of them to ("/")

Comment: This fix is in addition to what others have already suggested. display name does not have to form your rest api url. Make sure to use correct path to you web application first.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its the url which is causing the issue. seems like the context you are using contains the periods which is not a valid context name. trying changing the url to the application name(context) and it should work.

so

```
replace
"http://localhost:8080/com.boss.rest.example/api/getRandomRamp"

with 

"http://localhost:8080/contextname/api/getRandomRamp"
```

Comment: thank you, this was not the problem, but it's a useful information!

Answer (score 0):

How you deploy your application? Usually you have to do it to some server like Tomcat - and this server deploys it by certain name.

Also, `display-name` is Display Name, nothing else. Especially not deployment location.

Comment: thank you! yes, i'm deploying it to Tomcat, and i know that the display name is nothing more than the display name ;-)